# Checkbox opens form container and scroll to it; close button reset forms and unchecked the checkbox

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I'm working on a quit painful form and need someone help to figure it out.

This is what I want to have, but my javascript knowledge isn't the best =/:

> If a checkbox is :checked a container should open with some inputs. By
>   click on the checkbox it should scroll to the recently opened
>   container.
>
> In this container is a close-button, a input and a textarea. By click on the close button this one  should close the container and reset only the included inputs. That should also
>   work by unchecked the checkbox, but without scrolling.

[I built a codepen with my current code.](http://codepen.io/TimGr/full/aeEBu)

**This is my HTML**

```
<form method="" action="" name="form1">
  <fieldset>

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="one" class="class1"/>
      <span>Checkbox 1</span>
    </label> 

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="two" class="class2"/>
      <span>Checkbox 2</span>
    </label> 

    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="three" class="class3"/>
      <span>Checkbox 3</span>
    </label> 

      <div id="box1" class="xshow animated container">
      <h1>This opens because checkbox 1 is :checked</h1>
      <label>Text1:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="text1"/>
      <label>Textarea1:</label>
      <textarea name="textarea1"></textarea>
      <a class="closebutton">Close and Reset only text1 and textarea1</a>
    </div>

    <div id="box2" class="xshow animated container">
      <h1>This opens because checkbox 2 is :checked</h1>
      <label>Text2:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="text2"/>
      <label>Textarea2:</label>
      <textarea name="textarea2"></textarea>
      <a class="closebutton">Close and Reset only text2 and textarea2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="box3" class="xshow animated container">
      <h1>This opens because checkbox 3 is :checked</h1>
      <label>Text3:</label>
      <input type="text" value="" name="text3"/>
      <label>Textarea3:</label>
      <textarea name="textarea3"></textarea>
      <a class="closebutton">Close and Reset only text3 and textarea3</a>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**And my JS so far:**

```
/* ----------------------------- */
/* == 1 Checkbox + 1 Box     */
/* ----------------------------- */ 
$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox1]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#box1").removeClass("xshow").addClass("bounceIn");

} else {
    $("#box1").addClass("xshow");
    }
});


/*Close Button*/
$('.closebutton').click(function() {
     $("#box1").removeClass("bounceIn").addClass("xshow");
    $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox1]").attr('checked', false);
});





/* ----------------------------- */
/* == 2 Checkbox + 2 Box     */
/* ----------------------------- */ 
$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox2]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#box2").removeClass("xshow").addClass("bounceIn");

} else {
    $("#box2").addClass("xshow");
    }
});


/*Close Button*/
$('.closebutton').click(function() {
     $("#box2").removeClass("bounceIn").addClass("xshow");
    $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox2]").attr('checked', false);
});





/* ----------------------------- */
/* == 3 Checkbox + 3 Box     */
/* ----------------------------- */ 
$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox3]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#box3").removeClass("xshow").addClass("bounceIn");

} else {
    $("#box3").addClass("xshow");
    }
});


/*Close Button*/
$('.closebutton').click(function() {
     $("#box3").removeClass("bounceIn").addClass("xshow");
    $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox3]").attr('checked', false);
});
```

Would be totally awesome if someone can help me or give me a tip how to solve it by my own.

Thank you guys!!!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Hey David, thank you. i have edited my first post